# How to import method into Worker Scope in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code snippet

```js
class WebWorker {
  constructor(worker) {
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob(["(" + code + ")()"]);
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }
}

var thisWebWorker = new WebWorker(() => {
  self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    //i want to run sayHi method here
    sayHi()
  })
});


let sayHi = () => {
  console.log('Hi')
}

thisWebWorker.postMessage('run web worker')
```

How to import sayHi `sayHi()` method into web worker scope, i found this method `importScripts()` from [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) but i dont know how to use this

Answer (score 1):

Because the function passed to the constructor is going to be stringified, anything referenced needs to be self-contained inside that function; anything you want to reference must be scoped outside of it, otherwise it won't be included in the string and blob, and the worker won't be able to run it.

Define `sayHi` inside the function you pass:

```js
class WebWorker {
  constructor(worker) {
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob(["(" + code + ")()"]);
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }
}

var thisWebWorker = new WebWorker(() => {
  self.sayHi = () => {
    console.log('Hi')
  }
  self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    sayHi()
  })
});

thisWebWorker.postMessage('run web worker')
```

Another option is to put `sayHi` in a completely separate file, then import it:

```
// sayHi.js
let sayHi = () => {
  console.log('Hi')
}
```

```
var thisWebWorker = new WebWorker(() => {
  importScripts('sayHi.js');
  self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    sayHi()
  })
});
```

Comment: hi @CertainPerformance im looking for a way to import without using external js file, and not declaring this method inside the web worker, lets say this sayHi are the reuseable method that can be used not only inside the web worker listener, there is a way?

Comment: There's no *good* way. Defining it such that it's included in the scope of the stringified function, or having an external file, are the only two decent ways of approaching this. It would be technically possible to post a message from the parent to the worker and have the worker `eval` (or similar) the message, but that's really ugly, I wouldn't recommend it.